# Php JsonSerializeable - done right

Tags: php, json

im somehow new to php so this might look like a dumb question to you. I tried to google this but didnt find the method im looking for.

I have a custom class I want to serialize to json using the JsonSerializable interface in php 5.5. The code currently looks like this:

```
class MyClass implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $attr1;
    public $attr2;
    .....

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
       return array(
           'attr1' => $this->attr1,
           'attr2' => $this->attr2,
            ....
           );

    }
}
```

Now this became to look like bad code if you have like 20 instance variables in your object, which is why i want to refractor this method to something like this:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);  
}
```

Although get_object_vars should return an associative array ('attr1' => value1, ...), this leads to an empty json string if i want to serialize an array of objects:

```
$obj = new MyClass(..);
echo json_encode($obj); // this works. output: {"attr1":value1, ....}

$objarray = array(new MyClass(..), new MyClass(..));
echo json_encode($objarray); // this returns an empty string of length 0!
```

What am I doing wrong here?
If this is a totally wrong approach of doing this, im happy to get any hints :>

thanks in advance!

// UPDATE
After hours, i found the problem. I create the array of objects from a database and dit not set `charset=utf8`. As json_encode cannot handle other char sets, it returneed nothing.

Comment: Have you tried to reverse your logic on the last step? JSON encode each object before adding it to an array. I suppose you'd have to re-json-ize to get the outer array like you want.

Comment: @Jasper: He wants an array of objects, not of strings.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `json_encode` is going to return a string-representation of the object, correct?

Comment: @Jasper: Yes.  That's what it does.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://eval.in/131426

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm not understanding your comment. If `json_encode` comes into play, how could you want anything other than a string as a final result?

Comment: @Jasper: I was saying that if you did `array(json_encode(new MyClass(..)))` and then `json_encode`d that, you'd get a "double-encoded" string.  You'd have an array of strings that you would then re-encode into a string.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ah yeah, gotcha. Kind-of what I was thinking but it was just a shot in the dark. So what's the advantage to doing this rather than creating a function in your class that outputs JSON as you want?

Comment: @Jasper: You only want to call `json_encode` *once*, not multiple times.

Comment: @RocketHazmat My question there was ambiguous (probably because I don't really know how to ask what I'm asking), but in the end I think I'll just do some research on `JsonSerializable` rather than drive you nuts :)